# Why pointer used in node of a linked list is of type struct node and not data.Node?

Tags: c, struct, scope, declaration

Here is the declaration of structure which represent the node

```
  struct Node
{ 
     datatype data;
     struct Node *next;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `datatype.Node`?

Comment: What would the size of a `Node` be if it contained a `Node`, which contained a `Node`, which contained a `Node`, which contained a `Node`, which contained a `Node`, which contained a `Node`, which contained a `Node`, ... ?

Answer (score 2):

In C in this declaration (where you forgot to place a semicolon)

```
struct Node
{ 
     datatype data;
     struct Node *next;
};
```

there is declared type specifier `struct Node`. There is not declared a type specifier `Node`. `struct Node` and `Node` are not equivalent.

To introduce the name `Node` as an alias for the type specifier `struct Node` you could write

```
typedef struct Node Node;

struct Node
{ 
     datatype data;
     Node *next;
};
```

In C++ you may just write

```
struct Node
{ 
     datatype data;
     Node *next;
};
```

From the C++ 17 Standard (12 Classes)

> 2 A class-name is inserted into the scope in which it is declared
> immediately after the class-name is seen. **The class-name is also
> inserted into the scope of the class itself; this is known as the
> injected-class-name**.

C and C++ are two different languages with their own rules that often do not coincide.

For example in C you may write an expression like `sizeof( struct A { int x; } )` while in C++ such an expression is invalid.